# Why might Context.Request.Url fail to recognize HTTPS scheme?

Tags: .net, https

Very simply, I have a property/method that builds an absolute path to an image like so:

```
    public String Url
    {
        get
        {
            Uri rv_uri = new Uri(Context.Request.Url, Path);
            return rv_uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
    }
```

But, when the this property is accessed via HTTPS, the return value still shows an HTTP scheme. In testing, I've found that Context.Request.Url is "unaware" that it's operating under SSL.

Any known bugs with Context.Request.Url?

I will otherwise suspect the load balancer our hosting provider has in place is mucking things up. If that's the case, am I SOL?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the SSL connection gets terminated on a separate server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of the time, SSL is only to the load balancer.

This is done to reduce the load on the web servers and most of the time there is not need of SSL behind the firewall.

Comment: Any way to determine whether the initial connection came in over SSL in this case? I vaguely recall rackspace adding a header in such cases. Is doing so a standard practice to your knowledge? (I may eventually have to just query our hosting partner, but they're often a little dumbfounded with their own equipment, possibly b/c of employee turnover.)

Comment: Actually I believe you are correct. A Have you checked the incoming server variables/headers for a ssl header?

Comment: I was hesitant to test this in our production environment, since iis takes a break for a few seconds, when we release code, but a lull in the traffic provided a good opportunity. Turns out our balancer appends "HTTPS: on".